# SQL Server date format not working for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that updates a row in a table.
I'm using C# to pass all the parameters into the stored procedure like this:

```
public int editFestival(String festId, String festNaam, String festLocatie, String festDatum,
                        String festDuur, String festEindDatum, String festUrl)
{
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["project"].ConnectionString);
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("EditFestival", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festId", Convert.ToInt32(festId)));
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festNaam", festNaam));
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festLocatie", festLocatie));
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festDatum", Convert.ToDateTime(festDatum)));
                                 //Also tried ->       , SqlDbType.date)).Value = festDatum
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festDuur", Convert.ToInt32(festDuur)));
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festEindDatum", Convert.ToDateTime(festEindDatum)));
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@festUrl", festUrl));

sqlConnection.Open();
sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
sqlCommand.Transaction = sqlTransaction;
rows = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlTransaction.Commit();
return rows;
}
```

Although the String festDatum (which means festDate in english) is in a correct format (yyyy-MM-dd) it's not accepted by the stored procedure.

When I execute the stored procedure with my own given variables, this is what it generates:

```
USE [groep2_festivals]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[EditFestival]
        @festId = 1,
        @festNaam = N'Rock Werchter',
        @festLocatie = N'Werchter - Belge',
        @festDatum = 2013-07-01, --This is where it says that there's a syntax error near '-'
        @festDuur = 4,
        @festEindDatum = 2013-07-04,
        @festUrl = N'www.rockwerchter.be'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

When I manually surround both dates with single quotes it works fine.
What am I doing wrong? Or would it be as simple as surrounding the parameter inside the update statement with single quotes?

EDIT: This is the original stored procedure (should have posted this earlier)

```
USE [groep2_festivals]
GO
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[EditFestival] Script Date: 10/05/2013 12:44:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author: Robbie Vercammen
-- Create date: 10/05/2013
-- Description: Veranderd de gegevens van een bepaald festival
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EditFestival]
    (
    @festId int,
    @festNaam nvarchar(255),
    @festLocatie nvarchar(255),
    @festDatum date,
    @festDuur int,
    @festEindDatum date,
    @festUrl nvarchar(255)
    )
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE festivals
SET fest_naam = @festNaam, fest_locatie = @festLocatie, fest_datum = @festDatum,
    fest_duur = @festDuur, fest_einddatum = @festEindDatum, fest_url = @festUrl
WHERE fest_id = @festid
END
```

EDIT: What I'm trying
I execute the stored procedure from within management studio

[image: entering parameters here]

The generated code is already posted above ;)
When executing that it just says

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Comment: You say - "it's not accepted by the stored procedure.". Mind explaining exactly what that means?

Comment: As for executing SQL in SSMS - you need to use a date literal in SSMS. `2013-07-01` is not a date literal. Use `'2013-07-01'` instead. This is not an issue with the parameterized version (with dates). This assuming you are using the query window to run the query.

Comment: Would `Convert.ToDateTime(festDatum)` really give you a valid object of type `DateTime`?

Comment: What is the type of the `@FestDataum` and `@FestEindDatum` arguments to the stored procedure?  I suspect the stored procedure might be taking in string arguments and converting them into dates in the code.

Comment: @Oded It means that the stored procedure gives a syntax error near '-' at the first '-' occurrence in 2013-01-01. But when I surround that with single quotes it accepts it fine. The value is being passed as a parameter in C# the way I described above

Comment: @Oded I've posted the original stored procedure, how can I surround the date with single quotes?

Comment: You don't need to surround it in the Stored Procedure since you pass it in as a `DATETIME` parameter.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "it's not accepted by the stored procedure". That is not a clear description of what _is_ happening. Do you get errors? Exceptions? Something else?

Comment: @Oded I'm sorry, but i've edited my post again, that is the only error message I'm receiving and only if i'm running the sp in ms... in C# i'm throwing all exceptions that pass by

Comment: This looks like an SSMS issue then. Nothing to do with the stored procedure or your C#. Not sure what format it expects, but you can try all of the following: `'2013-07-01'`, `01-Jul-2013`, `#2013-07-01#`. This is SSMS trying to convert the string to a date and failing.

Comment: Alright, sorry for wasting you time guys. I decided to just pass everything as a string. The parameter will eventually end up as a date type anyway.

Comment: YYYYMMDD format will be accepted any way. Did you try to send your parameters as "20030701" ?

Comment: @Eralper This post is so old that I don't really know what I did. The only thing I know is that YYYY-MM-DD couldn't be parsed if the culture doesn't recognize it. YYYY/MM/DD does work, I'm not sure about YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 1):

Date literals in SQL and MSSQL Management Studio need to be enclosed in single quotes, unless a specific integer date format is being used, which is not the case here.

As for which formats will work... it will depend on the regional settings on the machine hosting the database. There are usually several different formats that will work. `'yyyy-MM-dd'` commonly does, is widely used and from the info you have posted also seems to work in your environment.

In T-SQL, the safest way to convert a date in a `varchar` to one of the date/time types is to use the [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function where possible, rather than leave the conversion to the database.

In C# however, you don't need to consider single quotes when passing parameters via the `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection. Quoting is taken care of for you when you choose the right `SqlDbType`. If you know the date is in a specific format, then you should parse the date parameter and pass it like this...

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@festDatum", SqlDbType.Date).Value = 
                          DateTime.ParseExact(festDatum, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And same for `festEindDatum`.

If you don't parse the date in a specific format, then you are leaving it to C# or the database to effectively guess the format according to regional settings of the local machine which could lead to problems when your code runs in a different environment.

Comment: Are you sure? In the original post I already said: Although the String festDatum is in a correct format (yyyy-MM-dd)...

Comment: Just tested it, still the same error message. I don't think the problem lies with c# but with the stored procedure itself

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is in the datatype in stored procedure `@festDatum date,`which is **date** and in your C# code `("@festDatum", Convert.ToDateTime(festDatum)` you are converting it to **datetime**.

Please try converting parameter type in stored procdeure from **date** to **datetime**

**Or** use **festDatum.ToShortDateString()** as value in c# code.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi and thanks, i've tried that already, nothing worked for me. But i've just converted it to nvarchar, which it always accepts. After all, the correct date format is formatted in c# and then send to the sp